# Show list of all routes in Akka HTTP

Tags: routes, url-routing, akka-http

I have a small Akka Http server.
Is there a way of listing all server routes/services?

Comment: You could give this library a try, which applies Swagger's form of endpoint documentation to Akka Http: https://github.com/swagger-akka-http/swagger-akka-http

Comment: I think the OP's question is more about getting the routes of the server in some programmatic fashion i.e once the server is up & running, is it possible to get the list of routes/endpoints it serves ?

Answer (score 4):

Currently this isn't simple without creating your own wrapper around the akka-http Scala DSL. More discussion here: https://github.com/akka/akka-http/issues/201

Long story short the Scala DSL isn't conducive to introspection.